# How to find full path to interpreter binary in C in linux if script uses #!/usr/bin/env foo

Tags: c, linux, bash, symlink, hashbang

I'm writing new script interpreter in C in linux. It is in ~/foo directory:

```
~/foo          - directory
~/foo/foo.c    - source
~/foo/foo      - compiled C binary
~/foo/data.txt - file with data the interpreter will need
```

I want to be able to run interpreter from command line so I put symlink in ~/bin (which I have in PATH):

```
~/bin/foo      - symlink to "~/foo/foo" binary
```

This works, when I type "foo" in terminal it runs the interpreter. Now I want to be able to run scripts using "#!/usr/bin/env foo" hashbang. I wrote this executable script in ~/test.fs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env foo
some foo code
```

When I run the script using ./test.fs it works, it is executed using foo interpreter. However in interpreter itself if I print argv[0] it contains just "foo". I tried to use realpath(argv[0], ...) function however it does not find the real path:

```
char resolved_path[MAXPATHLEN];
if(realpath(argv[0], resolved_path)) {
    printf("resolved_path=%s\n", resolved_path);
}
```

realpath("foo", resolved_path) does not return true because "foo" is in ~/bin but I am in other directory when I'm running the script.

In interpreter I simply need to find absolute path to "foo" binary even if it was executed via /usr/bin/env foo and ~/bin/foo is symlink.

If I knew the absolute path to ~/bin/foo I could use readlink to find target of that symlink but I don't know how to get from "foo" to "~/bin/foo".

Here is source of interpreter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("argv[0]=%s\n", argv[0]);
    char resolved_path[MAXPATHLEN];
    if(realpath(argv[0], resolved_path)) {
        printf("resolved_path=%s\n", resolved_path);
    }
    printf("actual interpreter stuff goes here...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Summary:

1. read argv[0] to be "foo"
2. find that executed file was actually "~/bin/foo"
3. if it is symlink find target
4. use realpath to find absolute path of binary

I am stuck at point 2.

I cannot put data to /usr/share/... or some other directory because this is still in development and I constantly need to edit files and I need multiple versions at the same time so the best way is to have data alongside the binary. Each version will have data next to the binary, this way I can have ~/foo1/foo, ~/foo2/foo, and so on. ~/foo1/foo will read ~/foo1/data.txt and ~/foo2/foo will read ~/foo2/data2.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to get from "foo" to "~/bin/foo".

On Linux, `readlink("/proc/$PID/exe")` is a symlink to the executable location.

If not on Linux, you would `getenv("PATH")` then split on `:` and for each directory check if `dir/foo` exists. The first one you find is the one.

Remember to handle errors. Not only the executable file might not exist itself, also `argv[0]` may be NULL or empty or be anything.

You are asking XY question. The question you did not ask, but I guess you are interested in:

> How should you tell your executable where to find `data.txt`?

You should not store data in `PATH`, only executables. Instead, your `foo` should take a command line parameter or read an environment variable (or both) that points to `data.txt` that you want to use, with a default inferred from `/usr` standard directory location. See endless command line examples, like `vim -u file` or `tmux -f file` or `docker --config string` or virtually any other command line tool.

You could then create a shell script in `~/bin` to just execute `foo -c ~/foo/data.txt "$@"`.

Some tools take a compile time parameter to specify the default location of its shared data. Like cmake has `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` or autotools does with --prefix to specify the default installation prefix. You would take this prefix and configure the default program shared data location to the one specified by the user at ~/foo/ at compile time.

Comment: The pid method works